# SQL Query for customer activity in any 24 hrs timframe

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

There is one table gross win in my database, which displays the amount the customer has won on a particular date.
For instance,

[Entries]

[image: 1]

![2]

I want to get the list of all the customers who have won more than 200 in 24 hrs time frame.
Could someone please help me out with that, not sure how to approach this
For instance in this image we have 3 customers with different account ids.
If we add up the sum of gross win for all the customers:
Customer with account Id 1: It is 150( Not more than 200)
Customer with account id 3: 250(Greater than 200)
Customer with account Id 4: 350( Greater than 200)

I want account id 3 and 4 as the output.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "24 hrs".  Do any of these meet your threshold?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, really appreciate it. I have made a few changes to the screenshot that I have pasted. Now , if we look at the screenshot there are three different customers with account Id's (1,3 and 4). If we add up the gross win of the customer: Customer with account Id 1 he has a gross win of 150 in 24 hrs time frame (which is not 200) for account Id 3 and Account Id 4 it is more than 200. So I want Account Id 3 and Account Id 4 as the output. how do I do that. Would really appreciate your help on that.

Comment: . . "3" does not meeting your threshold in 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. My bad, had that  not been  13 in the first entry ( but 16,or more)in the time stamp then yes it would have been in my threshold, but not in this case. Really appreciate your help sir. Thank you once again

Comment: what is your definition of `24 hrs timeframe` ? is it a rolling `24 hrs` window ? or the it is with relative to a specific time ?

Comment: It is not relative to a specific time, but within any 24 hrs window

Answer (score 2):

If you just want it per calendar day:

```
select accountid, convert(date, datetime), sum(grosswin)
from t
group by accountid, convert(date, datetime)
having sum(grosswin) > 200;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * FROM myTable WHERE DateTime > DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()) AND GrossWin > 200
```

——-

With additional information:

```
SELECT AccountID, SUM(GrossWin) as TotalWins
FROM myTable
WHERE DateTime > DateAdd(day, -1, getdate())
GROUP BY AccountID
HAVING SUM(GrossWin) > 200
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you answering my query, but I have a doubt on the same. I have used the following logic: Select * from mytable where datetime> dateadd(day,-1, datetime) as I want to get the results for any 24 hrs time frame. Wont the getdate() function give me the result only for last 24 hrs(Not sure of this, and would really appreciate your guidance). Also, In the screenshot that I have provided entries 3 and 4 also add up to more than 200. how do I get that as well. Please could you guide me on the same. Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you having to manually sum the GrossWins based on some other field? I don’t understand the “add up to more than 200” request. There’s no column that indicates which column is the “Customer Key”. Please redefine your question.

Comment: Also for the any 24-Hour timeframe just replace the getdate() with a time stamp “2021-01-05 08:00:00 AM” just be mindful of the time zone.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, really appreciate it. I have made a few changes to the screenshot that I have pasted. Now , if we look at the screenshot there are three different customers with account Id's (1,2 and 3). If we add up the gross win of the customer: Customer with account Id 1 he has a gross win of 150 in 24 hrs time frame (which is not 200) for account Id 3 and Account Id 4 it is more than 200. So I want Account Id 3 and Account Id 4 as the output. how do I do that.

Comment: Got it. Paste your table into the question. Linking to external screenshots is generally frowned upon on StackOverflow.

Comment: I now see the question is quite revised from the original. If you are looking for “within any 24-hour timeframe” my answer is not the best.

Answer (score 0):

use a `NOT EXISTS` to check for the condition `24 hours` and `SUM(GrossWin) >= 200`

```
select distinct e.[AccountId]
from   [Entries] e
where  exists
       (
           select [AccountId]
           from   Entries x
           where  x.[AccountId] = e.[AccountId]
           and    x.[DateTime] >= dateadd(hour, -24, e.[DateTime])
           and    x.[DateTime] <= e.[DateTime]
           group by [AccountId]
           having sum(x.[GrossWin]) >= 200
       )
```

OR a `CROSS APPLY` query

```
select distinct e.[AccountId]
from   [Entries] e
       CROSS APPLY
       (
           select GrossWin = sum(x.[GrossWin]) 
           from   Entries x
           where  x.[AccountId] = e.[AccountId]
           and    x.[DateTime] >= dateadd(hour, -24, e.[DateTime])
           and    x.[DateTime] <= e.[DateTime]
           group by [AccountId]
       ) g
where  g.[GrossWin] >= 200
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e923fb16101162d8be53af31757a55e5)